# Unable to mock Thrift classes in Grails for testing (GroovyCastException)

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking, thrift

For unit testing, I need to mock several Apache Thrift related Java classes (THttpClient, TBinaryProtocol, and a generated Client) being used in a Grails service, but have run into several exceptions when using the usual mocking techniques. I created getters in the service (instead of using new operators within the method being tested) which I am mocking. One issue addressed is that the Thrift classes do not have *default constructors*, so I created a subclass to meet requirements for mocking:

```
class TestableTHttpClient extends THttpClient {
     public TestableTHttpClient() {
         super("http://example.com");
     }
     public TestableTHttpClient(String url) {
         super(url);
     }
}
```

I have tried mocking using mockFor() but get a **GroovyCastException**: Error casting map to MyServiceTests$TestableTHttpClient, Reason: null:

```
def mockTHttpClient = mockFor(TestableTHttpClient, true)
mockTHttpClient.demand.open { }
mockTHttpClient.demand.close { }
def mockTHttpClientInstance = mockTHttpClient.createMock() // fails
```

I have tried map coercion with the same GroovyCastException: Error casting map to MyServiceTests$TestableTHttpClient

```
def mockTHttpClientInstance = [
    open: { },
    close: { }
] as TestableTHttpClient]
```

I have tried using closures with the same exception as above.

```
def helperMethod = { assert 1 == 1 }
def helper = [open:helperMethod, close:helperMethod]
def mockTHttpClientInstance = helper as TestableTHttpClient // fails
```

I made changes on the metaclass, which passed two of the classes, but the last class (Client) I need to return a specific mocked value. Instead, the real method was getting called: TTransportException: No more data available.

```
def mockTHttpClientInstance = new TestableTHttpClient()
mockTHttpClientInstance.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args -> }
def mockTBinaryProtocolInstance = new TestableTBinaryProtocol()
mockTBinaryProtocolInstance.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args -> }   
def mockClientInstance = new TestableClient()
// mockClientInstance.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args -> }
mockClientInstance.metaClass.methodINeedToMockResults = { String name -> true }

def mockMyService = [
    getTHttpClient: { String -> mockTHttpClientInstance },
    getTBinaryProtocol: { TTransport -> mockTBinaryProtocolInstance },
    getClient: { TProtocol -> mockClientInstance }
] as MyService
```

Any suggestions? I have already read over http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html and the Grails books I know of contain very little on testing other than domains and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different mocking frameworks. I recommend [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).